# Is there a time recorder plugin on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a plugin to record time that take between two point, for example, I want to add start and stop in the job configuration and get the time between those two points.

I found build trend plugin which is similar to what I want but it records the whole job time, not part of the job.

Answer (score -1):

If you can record your time somehow (using the build script itself), you can then plot it using the **[Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin)**

Comment: I am looking for a plugin to record time, not to generate the graph. :)

Comment: @Anonymous and how would you then present that information? Are you going to print it to console? Are you going to save it to an artifact file? Inject it into the artifact name?

Comment: If I can get that info, then I will log it to the database.